# unable to clear cache using react-clear-cache in react based spa

Tags: reactjs, browser-cache

I have installed the package **react-clear-cache** and followed its steps to add following script to **package.json** under scripts tag

```
{
  "prebuild": "npm run generate-build-meta",
  "generate-build-meta": "./node_modules/react-clear-cache/bin/cli.js"
}
```

and other script but found that is not working.
One thing I noticed that the build that is getting created is not creating any meta.json file. But unable to why its not getting created or what may be causing the issue.

Also noticed an error is getting shown in console=>>

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Need guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue. Simply do `npm run prebuild` before normal build.